# Is there a way to disable byte-range requests on the client side?

Tags: http, rfc2616

I understand that one can set `Accept-Ranges: none` on the server to advise the client not to attempt a range request.

I am wondering if there is a way to tell a browser not to attempt a range request without having to make any changes on the server.

For instance, is there a setting in Chrome or Firefox that I can toggle to deter my browser from making range requests?

Answer (score 1):

You answered the question in the first sentence.

The relevant RFC is [7233,          Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Range Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233):

> [2.3.  Accept-Ranges](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-2.3)

> A client MAY generate
> range requests without having received this header field for the
> resource involved.

> A server that does not support any kind of range request for the
> target resource MAY send

> ```
> Accept-Ranges: none
> ```

> to advise the client not to attempt a range request.

If you mean you want to know how to disable range requests in a browser altogether, consult the specific browser's documentation. A quick web search yielded no options for me to do this for common browsers.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it well to begin with.
I really want to know if there is a way to prevent the client from generating range requests in the first place.

Comment: Even after your edit I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. You can't control what browsers send to your server, so if it now handles range requests but you don't want it to, you'll have to reconfigure the web server or alter the code running on it.